# Vuetify text fields on one line

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have this template for a Vue component (See it in [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/vherasne/pen/dyyPBrp)):

```
<div class="some-class">
    <v-form >
        <v-container @click="someMethod()">
            <v-row>
                <v-col cols="3" sm="3" v-for="p in placeholders" :key="p">
                    <v-text-field :placeholder="p" single-line outlined >
                    </v-text-field>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
        </v-container>
    </v-form>
</div>
```

where `placeholders` is an array like:

```
['Title 1', 'Title 2', 'Title 3',...'Title 21']
```

and `some-class` is in the style section of the component:

```
<style>
    div.some-class {
        display: inline-block;
        max-width: 100%;
        overflow-x: auto;
    }
</style>
```

I would like to have them all on one line so I can scroll horizontally. But instead I get this:

[image]

How can I tweak the style to see all the text fields on one line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vuetify uses a flex grid. The reason that it's not overflowing is that you have to set the `flex-wrap` to `nowrap`.

Basically, just add the styles below to your `v-row`:

```
.nowrap-overflow {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Modified codepen here:
https://codepen.io/CodingDeer/pen/zYYGOGd

Comment: Thanks a lot @Cathy Ha I almost give up on this

Comment: Thanks helped me, worked for me with "margin-inline: auto"